# Нагрузка на БД

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить, не перегружает ли страница запросами базу данных (mysql). Т.е. как определить, например, допустимое число запросов на одной странице?

Comment: Как сказал уважаемый @фотон, нет допуст. числа кол. запросов, но есть время ожидания. Сугубо! мое личное мнение: где то 40-50 секундов хватить максимум на загрузки страницы.
Мораль: оптимизируйте запросы, постарайтесь сделать один большой запрос, и потом извлечьте в массив данных, и используете это массив как источник данных.

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, 40-50 секунд для загрузки страницы - это очень много..  По статистике получается так: если сайт (или его страница) не открылись максимум за 5 секунд - 90% пользователей уходит с этого сайта

Comment: ну, понимаю конечно. Но я как бы сказать,чисто по теорий привел эти данные. На практике,увы,40-50 с это кошмар))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.1 секунды - допустимый (для пользователя) предел генерации страницы. Исходите из этой величины. А что касается количества запросов - пусть хоть тысячу будет. Если сервер грамотно настроен - бояться нечего. Хотя это не исключает правильного отношения к БД. В случае сомнений - анализу предстоит каждый запрос.

Типичные говнопаттерны: запросы в цикле, идентичные запросы со 100500 джойнами, для получения А, Б, Ц (для получения каждой величины - отдельный запрос), ленивый программист лучше сделает двадцать запросов, чем подумает, как получить такой же результат одним запросом.

Answer (score 0):

Допустимого числа запросов не существует..  Но если запросов слишком много, то это плохо..

Нужен какой-нибудь профайлер..  Для Zend Framework есть [ZFDebug](http://code.google.com/p/zfdebug/), для остального - не знаю..

Answer (score -1):

приведу статистику: движок shopos. Как я выяснил, для генерации страницы выполняется около 300 запросов к БД О_О. Акции спокойно держит. Ну и сервак не нагруженный.

Comment: хотя 300 запросов это сущий ад. мда.

Comment: Если будет хотя бы 100 одновременных посещений - мускуль ляжет почти навернякаНу если конечно это не dedicated server с 4-мя 4-ядерными ксеонами и 32 гигами оперативки :)

Comment: @Photon, да я сам знаю, что ужас :) Когда узнал, какое количество запросов выполняется, чуть в обморок не упал. Возможно там еще кеш работает. Но не суть. 20-30 подключений держит спокойно.